# How to concatenate 2 columns,which contains np arrays, into a new column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

original dataframe

```
A                      B
np.array([1, 2, 3])    np.array([4, 5, 6])
np.array([7, 8, 9])    np.array([9, 10, 11])
```

wish it to be

```
A                      B                         C
np.array([1, 2, 3])    np.array([4, 5, 6])       np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
np.array([7, 8, 9])    np.array([9, 10, 11])     np.array([7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11])
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Keep in mind that columns of lists/arrays aren't a good idea in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
In [66]: df['C'] = [np.append(*x) for x in df[['A', 'B']].values]

In [67]: df
Out[67]:
           A            B                     C
0  [1, 2, 3]    [4, 5, 6]    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1  [7, 8, 9]  [9, 10, 11]  [7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11]
```

**Option 2:** `df['C'] = [np.concatenate(x) for x in df[['A', 'B']].values]`

**Option 3:** `df['C'] = map(np.concatenate, df[['A', 'B']].values)`

Test

```
In [69]: df.loc[0, 'C']
Out[69]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: what is there are more columns than A, B? And I just want to pin point A, B columns.